# How do I make this slash command respond to a certain string

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Let me just explain what I am trying to achieve here. I am trying to make it so that if a user executes a certain line of code, they will get a custom string like if someone was to say 'ping' it would say 'pong' and if someone said 'hi' it would say 'hello'.

I have tried multiple times to make this work yet I can't wrap my baby brain around it.

```
const ms = require('ms');
const { ApplicationCommandType, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'console',
    description: 'Developer Mode!',
    voiceChannel: false,
    options: [
    {
        name: 'Code',
        description: 'A line of code you wish to execute',
        type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
        required: true,
    }
    ],
async execute({ inter }) {
    const LineOfCode = ms(inter.options.getString('Code'));

    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setColor('#5679EF')
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
    .setTitle(" Console")
    .setDescription(`${LineOfCode} Execution Successfully`)

},
};
```

^ Code isn't fully complete as I am inexperienced with Discord.js v14

oh and one last thing, if the string the user put in the option box wasn't listed, I want it to say something custom for that as well :)

An example of the way I want it to work is:
**/console ping**
reply: pong (embed)
or
**/console hi**
reply: hello (embed)

And if you entered something that isn't on the list of things you can say:
**/console cake**
reply: This isn't available! (embed)

Comment: for clarification is the "code" option an example or are you attempting to add onto the "code" option?

Comment: So is the slash command supposed to start a listener for that string or are you trying to do it all in one, for example /console ping or just /console and then it waits for the string?

Comment: I am trying to add onto the code option

Comment: i want to do it all in one

Comment: @Gh0st sorry im new to this website lmao forgot to ping you guys for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me;

````
    const DiscordifyCredits = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor('#0CEC1D')
      .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL({ size: 1024, dynamic: true }) })
      .setTitle(' Console')
      .setDescription("```CodeBean's Discordify\n\nCoke (Team CodeBean)\nRakin (Additional Help)\nClorophyte (Team CodeBean)\nEdfour10 (Team CodeBean)\nVoltrex (Additional Help)\nSayuri (Additional Help)\nCollin (Additional Help)\n\nSpecial Thanks:\nDiscord\nNonay\nMethod Gaming\nToast_carno (Bug Testing)\nnerd (Bug Testing)```")
      .setFooter({ text: 'Powered by Nonay', iconURL: inter.member.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })});
    
      const text = inter.options.getString('code');
    
      switch (text) {
        case "import = discordify print(credits)":
        await inter.reply({ embeds: [DiscordifyCredits] })
        break;
        case 'baz':
        await inter.reply({ content: 'biz' });
      }
    
    },
    };
````